# How to bind the property of nested element to the viewmodel property

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have markup like following

**XAML**

```
    <ComboBox Grid.Row="0" Margin="15,54,352,231" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding OptimizationTypes}" DisplayMemberPath="TypeName"
                      SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                <ComboBox.DataContext >
                    <viewModels:MyViewModel />
                </ComboBox.DataContext>
                <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsItemEnabled}" />
                    </Style>
                </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ComboBox>
```

**ViewModel**

```
using System.Collections.Specialized;

namespace WpfApplication
{
    public class MyViewModel : INotifyCollectionChanged
    {
        public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;
        public bool IsItemEnabled { get; set; }

        public MyViewModel(IBaseControlElement baseControlElement)
        {
            //some code
        }
    }
}
```

The Boolean property *IsItemEnabled* located on the my viewmodel doesn't accesible for this setter and binding doesn't work. As far as i see binder trying to find the property not in MyViewModel. How to fix it? Can i set datacontext only for the combobox, or there are any others approaches in this case?

Comment: Why can't you use a view model with a non-parameterless constructor as the DataContext? And what has this to do with any binding error you are getting?

Comment: What exactly error do you get? None of us magician, we just programmers.

Comment: _"hasn't parameterless constructor and therefore can't be as data context"_ -- non-sequitur. Having a parameterless constructor is not a prerequisite for being a `DataContext` value. Indeed, in a `ComboBox`, one's view model objects are often created in code-behind, not XAML, and passing parameters to a constructor is trivial. Whatever's going on in your code, it's not because the object has no parameterless constructor. Please fix your question. See [mcve] and [ask], for starters.

Comment: It`s just tool tip: The type MyViewModel does not include any accessible constructors

Comment: Sorry. I have changed my question. Let's forget about datacontext and my conclusions about it. In any case, how to do it

Comment: Could anybody help? Or this site only for votes about the questions? The most questions is could be answered even without any code. But only not here probably.

Comment: You are probably making this too complex. Do you need to set both the datacontext and the itemssource? Usually just setting the source will do. Without seeing the viewmodel it's hard to see what you are trying to do.

Comment: You are not showing us how you bind to the page's datacontext the viewmodel. That will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.IsItemEnabled,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ComboBox}}" />
```

Comment: I got the new tooltip with text: Can not resolve property IsItemEnabled in datacontext of type object. Where and how i should set the datacontext?

Comment: I guess I assumed from what you wrote, but your MyViewModel has a public bool IsItemEnabled { get; set; } or something similar?

Comment: Yes it has that property

Comment: Whats the exact error? The output window in VS should output the error.

Comment: System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'IsItemEnabled' property not found on 'object' ''OptimizeType' (HashCode=42284632)'. BindingExpression:Path=IsItemEnabled; DataItem='OptimizeType' (HashCode=42284632); target element is 'ComboBoxItem' (Name=''); target property is 'IsEnabled' (type 'Boolean')

Comment: So, it went back up the visual tree and found a combobox, the datacontext for this combobox as a OptimizeItem. Are you sure you put AncestorType=ComboBox and not AncestorType=ComboBoxItem?

Comment: Also, might need to make it {Binding Path=DataContext.IsItemEnabled,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=ComboBox}} as I may have forgotten to set the mode

Comment: When i tried to add DataContext to combobox i've got exception: No default constructor found for type 'MyViewModel'. You can use the Arguments or FactoryMethod directives to construct this type.

Comment: Thats fine, but then where is MyViewModel bound? This is the element the relativesource needs to reference.

Comment: As shown in the code below  <ComboBox.DataContext>
            <local:MyViewModel />
        </ComboBox.DataContext>